# Can I use more than a single filter on a variable in template?

Tags: python, django, templates, filter

For example:

```
{{test|linebreaksbr|safe}}
```

Comment: Rather than asking, why didn't you just try it and see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, this is common practice to string together many filters consecutively.

Could you turn debugging on and see what the error is and update the question?

Make sure this is set in your settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, have you tried it?  Did something go wrong?

Comment: yeap, i did the very above, but it only had linebreaksbr effect, and not the safe filter in effect. which is what sparked this very question.

Comment: update the question with more details then: what went in, and what came out?